# Kernel Oops in Openwrt firmware while restarting network , finding the reason

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, openwrt

I have been facing the following(given below) kernel oops while restarting network in my device loaded with openwrt based firmware. Since proc_register is the topmost in the call trace , I verified the registration is successful for igmp_hwnat (device specific driver). The kernel  being used is 3.18. I am working with kernel related crashes for the first time. It would be really helpful if anyone have clues on how to go forward debugging it or what the reason could be for such issues. There is no side effects to this oops message.

Thanks in Advance.

```
    root@OpenWrt:/# /etc/init.d/network restart
    root@OpenWrt:/# [  573.100000] ecnt_register_hook fail, igmp_hwnat_multicast_undrop already registered
    [  573.110000] ecnt_register_hook fail, clear_multicast_flood_hwentry already registered
    [  573.120000] ------------[ cut here ]------------
    [  573.120000] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 2170 at fs/proc/generic.c:527 proc_register+0x150/0x1a4()
    [  573.130000] proc_dir_entry 'tc3162/igmp_hwnat' already registered
    [  573.130000] Modules linked in: xt_length xt_comment xt_multiport
    [  573.140000] CPU: 0 PID: 2170 Comm: netifd Tainted: G        W      3.18.21 #1
    [  573.150000] Stack : 00000000 00000004 00000006 80084b8c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
              803e57f2 00000041 00000000 00000000 0000020f 8fbaae50 8033c45c 803a4263
              0000087a 00000000 803e45dc 8fbaae50 00000001 0000000a 00000014 800857e8
          803a84e0 8004f01c 00000000 00000000 803418ec 8f04fcc4 8f04fcc4 8033c45c
          00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
          ...
[  573.180000] Call Trace:
[  573.180000] [<80037fac>] show_stack+0x50/0x84
[  573.190000] [<80195f68>] dump_stack+0x64/0x84
[  573.190000] [<8004f19c>] warn_slowpath_common+0x84/0xb4
[  573.200000] [<8004f1f8>] warn_slowpath_fmt+0x2c/0x38
[  573.200000] [<801380fc>] proc_register+0x150/0x1a4
[  573.210000] [<80138198>] create_proc_entry+0x48/0x7c
[  573.210000] [<802e52a8>] igmp_hwnat_init+0x98/0xcc
[  573.220000] [<80232b68>] alloc_netdev_mqs+0x17c/0x2f4
[  573.220000] [<802de1a8>] br_add_bridge+0x30/0x80
[  573.230000] [<802dfe2c>] br_ioctl_deviceless_stub+0x288/0x2c0
[  573.230000] [<80219310>] sock_ioctl+0x1dc/0x320
[  573.240000] [<800fd030>] do_vfs_ioctl+0x61c/0x688
[  573.240000] [<800fd0ec>] SyS_ioctl+0x50/0x94
[  573.250000] [<80022588>] handle_sys+0x128/0x14c
[  573.250000]
[  573.250000] ---[ end trace 020d72816f719b36 ]---

root@OpenWrt:/#
```

Comment: The warning message - `proc_dir_entry 'tc3162/igmp_hwnat' already registered` - is pretty clear: you tried to register entry which already has been registered before. It may be that your driver has registered the entry when previously loaded, but has not unregistered it after unloading.

Comment: Thankyou for the quick reply. Really appreciate it.